# Promises chaining

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am begining in node and I have a problem, I need to do this only with promises by node versions, I need to make a comparison with the result of previous promises but dont works, it seems  me that  is code that is poorly structured , here the code thanks ...

```
ListarUsuariosMaxDate.then(response => {
    return ListaconCondicionProceso(response);
}).then(data2 => {
    return filtrarPagos.then(data3 => {

            let result = data3.filter(elem => data2.filter(elem2 => elem.user == elem2.user_id && elem.createdAt > elem2.maximo).length > 0);

            return result;

        }).then(data5 => {

            console.log(data5)

        })

    })


})
```

the result (data5) is emtpy...sorry about the mistake...

Comment: Can you store the results of previous promises and compare as you go?

Comment: data3 and data2 have the data, that I need comape, let result = data3.filter(elem => data2.filter(elem2 => elem.user == elem2.user_id && elem.createdAt > elem2.maximo).length > 0)

Comment: Wrapping your synchronous filter option in a promise is an anti-pattern.  No need to do that.  You can just `return result` from within the `.then()` handler without wrapping it in a new promise.

Comment: i did and the result is the same, []

Comment: Did you `console.log(result)` and see what you have there?  What is the value there?

Comment: Also, why are you doing `filtrarPagos.then()`?  Where did `filtrarPagos` come from?  Is it a promise?  Or should you be calling it as a function?

Comment: filtrarPagos is a promose and a is a Json arrays , and  compare with anothe Json arrays and console.log en empty [ ]

Answer (score 0):

I could do it something change and works, but I don't understand why. I had in my previous code with async and await this structure, and it worked:

```
  async function comparacionTotalProceso(listaTotal, listaFiltrada) {


            let result = listaFiltrada.filter(elem => listaTotal.filter(elem2 => elem.user == elem2.user_id && elem.createdAt > elem2.maximo).length > 0);

            return result;
        });
    }
```

but now for node version, I need to change everything to promises and I did this:

```
...

.then(data2 => {
        return filtrarPagos.then(data3 => {

            let result = data2.map(elem => data3.map(elem2 => elem.user == elem2.user_id && elem.createdAt > elem2.maximo).length > 0? elem:null);

            return result;

        })
```

and finally works changed the filter for map and return elem, but I don't know why.